# How can I get my website menu to stay at the top of the page when the user scrolls down?

Tags: drupal, menu, css-position

The site I'm working on is www.delta-ups.co.uk. What I want is when the user has scrolled down and the menu goes out of sight, I would like the menu to be fixed at the top of the page so it doesn't scroll out of sight.

How could I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add css style to your element. Like this:

```
.menu{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
}
```

I'm assuming you're using a class selector.